# How can I check if a string can be converted to a float?

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion

First my context is that of a compiler writer who needs to convert floating point literals (strings) into float/double values. I haven't done any floating point programming the last 15 years so i'm pretty sure this is a total stupid newbie question.

```
double res; 
errno=0; 
*res = strtod((const char*)literal,NULL); 
if (errno==ERANGE) throw_a_literal_out_of_range_exception();
return res;
```

but there is no "strtof" function in the c runtime library?

EDIT: To clarify. I already know that the string 'literal' is a valid pattern for a C floating point. It already passed a regular expression test. I just want to check if there is a range/precision problem.

The reason is in Eiffel source code a user can write

```
a := {REAL_32} 3.1415
b := {REAL_32} 3.0E200
```

To cast a written floating point number explit to a 32bit floating point. I think in the second case the compiler should detect that the value is out of range and raise an error or at least a warning.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a float instead of double?

Comment: I think you should convert your literal to a double. Then proceed with the cast. At cast time, you should check if the double value is within range of a float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have your value in a `double`, you can just check if it's outside of the range of `float`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double d = FLT_MAX;
    if (argc > 1) {
        d = strtod(argv[1], NULL);
    }
    if ((d > 0 && (d > FLT_MAX || d < FLT_MIN))
                || (d < 0 && (d < -FLT_MAX || d > -FLT_MIN)))
        printf("Invalid float: %g\n", d);
    else
        printf("Valid: %g\n", d);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Running the program:

```
$ ./a.out
Valid: 3.40282e+38
$ ./a.out 3.5e38
Invalid float: 3.5e+38
$ ./a.out -1e40
Invalid float: -1e+40
```

You may or may not need to add a test for correct `strtod()` return, depending upon whether there's a possibility of an overflow in `double` type as well.

Answer (score 9):

In C89 you may use sscanf.

For example:

```
float myfloat;

if(sscanf(str, "%f", &myfloat) != 1)
    /* String could not be converted */
else
    /* String was converted, myfloat is usable */
```

Answer (score 6):

@Nicholas Goy:
I don't think `sscanf(str, "%f, &float) == 1` (or `!= 1`) really does what's desired.

If there are additional characters in `str` (e.g. "1.1foo"), it will parse without error, which is probably undesirable.  This can be rectified by doing:

```
char dummy;
if (sscanf(str, "%f%c", &float, &dummy) != 1) {
   /* Parse error. */
} else {
   /* Parsed cleanly. */
}
```

instead.  However, `sscanf` with `%f` is likely to use `strtod` internally and cast to float anyway.  The language in the C standard says:

> a,e,f,g Matches an optionally signed floating-point number, infinity, or NaN, whose
>   format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the strtod
>   function. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to floating.

which sort of implies this, and it seems to be true for me (gcc 4.2.1 on FreeBSD).  Using the above `sscanf` code, "1.79e308" parses successfully but has the value +inf, as does "5e-300" with the value 0.0, and these are the same results you'd get from `(float) 1.79e308` and `(float) 5e-300`.

Anyway.  All that said, I question why the OP wants to use float instead of double anyway.

Comment: Because i'm writing an Eiffel compiler (well it's a huge Eiffel->C preprocessor) and user can write "{REAL_32}3.1415" to get a 32bit real number instead of default 64bit. I think the compiler should throw an error or warning if the source code already contains a precision loss. And by the way, i already know that the string is a pure syntax valid floating point number string, i only care about range and precision errors. Sorry - i missed this detail in the question.

Comment: Well, I don't know how strict the OP wanted the conversion, but yea, my scanf code will ignore trailing char (as strtod).

Comment: @Nicholas Goy: strtod won't return an error on the trailing char, but you at least can use the end pointer to verify that it's pointing to the expected end of the string. The scanf code provides no advantage over strtod.

Answer (score 5):

I was going to say, simply use the code you already have, but assign the result of strod() to a float instead of a double. But your code is wrong in several ways.

Firstly, you cannot test errno unless an error has ocurred. Secondly, strtod() will not set errno except for things like range errors. If you pass it an invalid number, like "XYZ", it will not be set.

More correct use of strtod is:

```
char *p;
double d = strtod( "123.4xyz", & p );
if ( * p != 0 ) {
   // not a number - in this case will point at 'x'
}
```

Using strtod() to read a float, you may lose some precision, but that's the price you pay for using floats - in general, unless you have a very good reason not to, you should always prefer the use of double to float.

Comment: Yes of course - I seem to be having a few problems this afternoon. Thanks.

Comment: Well the lexer already gives me a lexical valid number sequence. The only thing i have to do is looking for range errors. Thats why i have written that i'm builing a compiler. I think it should give a warning when the literal value is wrong and the compiler can detect this.

Comment: In that case I'd take the easy way out and not support the float type, only doubles. floats aren't particularly useful.

Comment: Well unfortunately there is an Eiffel language standard i have to implement. And too many 3rd party libraries use floats in there API

Answer (score 4):

`strtof` does not exist in C89, but it does in C99.

Comment: Okay i forgot to mention the compiler: MSVC 2005.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest converting to double first, then cast to float. If the relative difference, `(f-d)/f`, is greater than float precision (roughly, `1e-7`) then there are more digits than what can be safely stored in float.

Answer (score 2):

On MSVC you can use [_atoflt()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5948ysye.aspx), defined in stdlib.h