# Check whether an input string consists out of specific characters -> Floating point Number

Tags: c, string, parsing, floating-point-conversion

I am an absolute beginner in (c) programming and I have to find a solution for the following problem:

I have to parse command line arguments to floats in a struct. This works quite well using `argc`, `argv` and `atof`. But is there an  way to check, whether the user used valid "float-characters" (`0-9` and `.`) in his input?

`atof` only returns its error `0.0` when there isn't any number at the beginning of the string to parse. If the user writes for example `./programname 4,5`, `atof` would still write `4` into my float...

I would have to check every single submitted character and in addition, set a counter to check, whether the user used more than one `.`. How can I achieve this efficiently?

EDIT:
Thank you vor your answers! My program is intended to convert only strings that consist of integers from `0` to `9` and a `.`. I forgot to mention that! I now try to write a function, that compares the input string to a string containing the valid chars using one for and one while loop. As I only want to check the second and the third argmunent of argv (`argv[1]` and `argv[2]`), I use a second for loop outside the rest to achieve that...

Comment: What about `"-3"`, `"1e-3"` and the like? Shall they be rejected since they do not just consist of digits and `.`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sscanf` and a dummy character to see if the complete string was converted or not, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1936079/256138):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char dummy;
  float f;
  if(sscanf(argv[1], "%f%c", &f,&dummy) != 1)
    printf("Input error.\n");
  else
    printf("%f\n", f);
}
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad088a869120b034)

Comment: But this will happily convert `"1e-3"`. Not sure if this is intended.

Comment: Thank you vor your answer! My program is intended to convert only strings that consist of integers from `0` to `9` and a `.`. I forgot to mention that! I now try to write a function, that compares the input string to a string containing the valid chars using one for and one while loop. As I only want to check the second and the third argmunent of argv (`argv[1]` and `argv[2]`), I use a second for loop outside the rest to achieve that...

Comment: Then I suggest a manual check for the format. Or a regex, but then you'd have two problems.