# Float Checking from Char Array for Limit, Character Checking Front and Back

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point

I am creating a simple Console application where its char *argv[] are expected to be in the form of floating number (such as 5.234, 7.197, and so on)

To ensure that the program only receive user inputs which are truly valid float, I created a function which combines sscanf (ref: [character array to floating point conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836866/character-array-to-floating-point-conversion)) and valid range checks (ref: [How can I check if a string can be converted to a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935501/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-can-be-converted-to-a-float)) results.

```
//buffer comes from agrv[n]
char MyFloatCheck(char* buffer)
{
    float f;
    char result;
    result = sscanf(buffer, "%f", &f);
    result &= isRangeValid(buffer);
    return result;
}
```

Then I tested the the function above with:

1. Valid input: 12.15
2. Very large input: 4 x 10^40
3. Invalid inputs: (a) ab19.114, (b) 19.114ab

The results for my test no 1, 2, and 3(a) are expected:

1. 1
2. 0 (because it is too large)
3. (a) 0 (because it contains the invalid characters in front of the number)

However the result for 3 (b) is unexepected:

3. (b) 1 (??)

My questions are:
1. Why is that so?
2. Is there any built-in way to check this kind of input error?
3. Is there any well established workaround?

I am thinking of making my own function which checks the character from the right end to see if it contains invalid characters, but if there is any available built-in way, I would rather use it.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, `sscanf` consumes characters one by one and writes the number that has been read in `%f` regardless of whether the reading stopped because of the end of the input string, a space, a newline, or a letter.

You would get the same behavior from `strtof`, a simpler substitute for `sscanf(buffer, "%f", &f);`:

```
char *endptr;
f = strtof(buffer, &endptr);
```

The above two lines give you a simple way to check that the entire string has been consumed after the call to `strtof`:

```
if (endptr != buffer && *endptr == 0) …
```

The condition `endptr != buffer` means that a floating-point number has been read. Otherwise, `f` is zero but that doesn't mean anything since no character was consumed. `*endptr == 0` means that the entire input buffer was consumed in reading the floating-point number, which appears to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This sounds logical... Unfortunately I am not with my laptop now... Will be back to be able to check after a couple of days. Nevertheless, you will have my upvote first.. again, thanks..